# MySql - Seq_in_index, update on duplicate key and dead locks

Tags: mysql, triggers, deadlock, on-duplicate-key

I am trying to figure out if the order of values in a insert effect the **Seq_in_index**  when using **update on duplicate key**, I have a dead lock that I am trying to debug.

So for example we have

A view table that gets a insert for every view and it has triggers set for insert,update, and delete effecting 5 other tables

one of the tables effected by the triggers is indexed like so

```
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Index_type |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+------------+
| tableA |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | field1      | BTREE      |
| tableA |          0 | PRIMARY  |            2 | field2      | BTREE      |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+------------+
```

now what I am asking is if the inset trigger ran like so

```
insert into tableA (field1, field2) vals (...) on duplicate key update ...
```

and the update trigger ran at the same time with the field order flipped

```
 insert into tableA (field2,field1) vals (...) on duplicate key update ...
```

could this result in a dead lock like

```
connection 1: locks key(1), locks key(2);
connection 2: locks key(2), locks key(1);
```

or would it lock the keys by the Seq_in_index regardless on the field order.

Comment: The example given above shows a composite key (i.e. a single key with two attributes), not separate/distinct keys...

Comment: ok so then what you are saying is that it has the 1 key and locks key(1) and my concern is not relevant. And if it was indexed like      `+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+
| test  |          0 | field1   |            1 | field1      |
| test  |          0 | field1   |            2 | field2      |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+`

Comment: let me redo that, did not know i had 5 min to save. ok so then what you are saying is that both fields are treated as 1 key together and locks as `locks key(1)` only and my concern is not relevant but if it was indexed where feild1 and field2 were set as a unique pair then this could be an issue which it is not.

Comment: Honestly, without further research, I'm not certain enough to give you any definite answers.  My previous comment was merely an observation.  It's a very interesting question which already has my +1.  If answers aren't forthcoming, give me a nudge and I'll offer a bounty / do some research; otherwise, you might have more luck over at [dba.se].

Comment: Cool, thanks for taking the time to look. I didn't even pick up one the composite when I first looked at it(lots on my plate). I know a really good DBA I will see if I can not get an answer from him and post my findings. Thanks!